# UILabel text gets cut off

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to dynamicly set label size. It works in a strange way, i get some of the text cut off.
I first set my label text and then try to resize it like this way.

```
    _switch2Label.text = @"Call on alarm, there will be no call if other user of alarm system will recieve an alarm call and confirm (answer) it by pressing 0#";
    _switch2Label.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self newFrame:_switch2Label];

- (void) newFrame:(UILabel *) label
{

    CGSize maxSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    maxSize.width = maxSize.width - 30;
    CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

    CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = labelSize.height;
    label.frame = newFrame;

}
```

I only get three lines of text, while five is needed for this label. Maybe anyone could see my mistake here? If I add more text to label it gets shown, yet still about two lines of the label text gets cutt off.

Comment: try to change maxSize to MAXFLOAT,maxSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFOAT,self.view.bounds.size.width-30);

Comment: Try this-
maxSize.width = label.frame.size.width;

Comment: Rahul, that did worked, write this as an answer and I will accept it. And if you can - could you explain a little bit, why width is the case?? I got height computed wrong, not width, so it's a little bit unclear to me.

Comment: Your width is fine. Pass a big number for the maxSize.height. The returned height will be what is needed.

Comment: For some reason it was not fine. Passing big number did not help either. I will repeat myself, i got it properly working by changing maxSize.width = label.frame.size.width. Checked that with tons of text, and the label resizes as charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your method...Please check it..it may help you..

```
- (void) newFrame:(UILabel *) label
{
     CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300, 1000.0f);
     CGSize size_txt_overview1 = [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:15] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
     label.frame = CGRectMake(20,20, size_txt_overview1.width, size_txt_overview1.height+15);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 _switch2Label.text = @"Call on alarm, there will be no call if other user of alarm system will recieve an alarm call and confirm (answer) it by pressing 0#,";
 _switch2Label.numberOfLines = 0;
 [self newFrame:_switch2Label];



- (void) newFrame:(UILabel *) label
{

    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, 10000);
    //maxSize.width = maxSize.width - 30;
    CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = labelSize.height;
    label.frame = newFrame;

}
```

Use this code blocks , may help u.

Comment: Why bother with the `lines:` method? Just set `numberOfLines` to 0. As long as the label's height is set, it will display properly.

Comment: hmmm , you are ri8, I edited my answer., thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Working answer as well. Thank you for your time! Yet there were correct answers earlier, so I will accept the ones earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Why programatically resizing the label? Is this something you cannot do in IB or using [autorezizeMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The label's constraint size isn't getting calculated as you intend, currently, your code is constraining the label height to the view's bound's height. Changing your maxSize instance to:

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 30, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = ...
```

Doing so will ensure that the constraint is not bound by your view bounds. You may also want to consider setting the clipsToBounds property of your view if you want the label to be able to extend past your view's bounds.

Comment: Sorry, tried it in your way, but such way it does not resize at all. Please look at Rahul comment, such way I got it working.

Comment: @Datenshi Sorry, was sending the wrong value to the second parameter. Edited to include proper code.

Comment: The values are backward. `CGSizeMake` takes width, height, not height, width.

Comment: @Datenshi, rmaddy is correct, that should do it. I mixed up the parameters.